# ObjectMapper array error

Tags: ios, swift, objectmapper

I have this json:

```
    Optional(<__NSSingleObjectArrayI 0x600000016530>(
{
    direccion = "";
    geo =     {
        coordinates =         (
            "25.65313",
            "-100.3611"
        );
        type = "";
    };
    nombre = "Mi Ubicacion";
}
)
)
```

and my model is this:

```
class LocationModel: Mappable {
    var nombre = ""
    var direccion = ""
    var geo = GeoModel()

    init(){

    }

    required init?(map: Map) {

    }

    // Mappable
    func mapping(map: Map) {
        nombre <- map["nombre"]
        direccion <- map["direccion"]
        geo <- map["geo"]
    }

}
```

and this is how im mapping it:

```
locationsGuardadas = Mapper<LocationModel>().mapArray(JSONArray: locationsJson as! [[String : Any]])
```

that code worked fine until a few days ago, when i updated my sdk to support ios 11.3, then the code stopped working, i have tried updating the objectmapper pod, and reseting simulator content and settings, but for some reason now, when i map the array, the "coordinates" array of the location comes without coordinates, it has a 0 count, and i dont know how to fix this problem, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: In Swift 4, ObjectMapper is no longer needed. You can create your own mapping directly using the Codable protocol.

Comment: so, ObjectMapper stopped working for swift 4? because if i have to make the change i will have to change a lot of lines, or is still usable? if it is still usable, is there a way to fix my problem?

Comment: I don't know whether it stopped working; I'm just saying that there's now a simpler way, with no reliance on external pods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have already found the problem, for some reason the ObjectMapper doesn't work well with float numbers, so changing every float to double did the trick